# Flutter installation produces error "cmdline-tools component is missing"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to install Flutter and Android Studio.

I have also seen several tutorials on YouTube but even if I carry out the same steps I always get the same two errors.

These are the mistakes:

```
 Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

I have already downloaded the cmdline through Android Studio and changed different paths but even doing so it doesn't keep me going.

While for the licenses it tells me that I have to install the cmdline first. So it brings me back to the first mistake.

Comment: On executing path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" from your terminal, what is the output/error do you get?

Comment: the error is: C:\ProgramFiles\Android\AndroidStudio is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or batch file.

Comment: go to android studio ang open the sdk manager and under sdk tools install the android sdk command-line tools or you can run a test flutter project it will install itself during build process...

Comment: Already tried both ways but it always gives me error

Comment: In Windows `C:\ProgramFiles` actually contains a space between `Program` and `Files`. I suggest you just install using the proper installer and then double click the icon to start Android Studio.

Comment: i tried but no, always same error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In the Android Studio software, you click on the menu Tools >> SDK Manager
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGJRM.png)

Step 2: In the SDK Manager setting screen, select the "SDK Tools" tab. Then tick "Android SDK Command-line Tools (lastest)". Finally click "Apply" to start the installation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBaHR.png)

Step 3: After installing "Command-line Tools" you can open a command line window to continue to confirm "Android licenses"

flutter doctor --android-licenses
Done ! Check Flutter doctor to make sure everything is fully installed. Good luck.